# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_initText'

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

Error I am getting is (In the console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_initText'      kinetic.js:52
```

I am trying to add simple Text to my canvas (using Kinetic.Js) like this

```
var simpleText = Kinetic.Text();
```

As soon as I commment this line out, there is no error or warning. But when I keep this I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the fact that it's Text with capital T it is a constructor function and you have to new it up.

```
var simpleText = new Kinect.Text()
```

Check out [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/) tutorial for example usage. More about JavaScript naming conventions [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Comment: Thanks. that was stupid of me to forget such a obvious thing. Thanks very much.